# LAPACK function dpotrs in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, linear-algebra, lapack

I am trying to translate some python code to matlab and I am not able to understand the equivalent of a LAPACK function.

In particular, in Python, there is this function `scipy.linalg.lapack.dpotrs` from the LAPACK package that I would like to replicate in matlab.

Citing from the [LAPACK library](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dpotrs.f.html) this function:

> solves a system of linear equations A*X = B with a symmetric positive definite matrix A using the Cholesky factorization A = U**T*U or A = L*L**T computed by DPOTRF.

Basically, the inputs of the function are as follow:

```
C = scipy.linalg.lapack.dpotrs(L, b, lower=True)
```

where

```
L = [[1.000, 0],[0.878723846, 0.477330496]]
```

and

```
b = [-1, -1]
```

The resulting output is

```
C = [-0.53227621, -0.53227621]
```

I am not able to understand this `dpotrs` routine as I am not proficient in Fortran.
When I try to firstly use the Cholesky decomposition and then solve the system of linear equations, I get an error as `L` is not positive definite.

How would you code this function in matlab? (or in Python using the numpy library) without using the LAPACK library?

Comment: As I read the LAPACK description you linked they are saying you pass a triangular matrix to dpotrs, which then solves the equations, The cholesky factorisation is done bt dpotrf which its assumed you called with your positive definite matrix. dpotrs does not itself do any factorisation; it merely solves the equations.

Comment: @dmuir I don't think so. If it were just solving the system of linear equations the solution would be [-1,-0.2541] and not [-0.53227621, -0.53227621]. So I guess there is something else going on